# Datasets representing image features

Tags: matlab, dataset, information-visualization

Ive been researched Information Visualization techniques application to image collections. I need some image datasets with features. Ideally, would be good find a dataset in a file representing each image attributes value,like this https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Corel+Image+Features so I could project on my software, but it has been too hard to find, so I am trying to work with matlab algorithms to extract the features. So, I want some datasets.

Comment: So what is the question here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://risenet.iti.upv.es/webupv-datasets/dwld/v2013/feats_visual/) you can find the [ImageCLEF 2013 dataset](http://risenet.iti.upv.es/webupv-datasets/) with different features: GIST, Color Histograms, SIFT, C-SIFT, RGB-SIFT and OPPONENT-SIFT.